# First order ODE - appropriate method

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the following ODE

$y'(x)=2y -x$

I tried to solve it with the method of variation of constants and it worked.

I considered the homogenous equation without the last term ($-x$),and I found the solution of the homogenous equation $y_h=C e^{2x}$.

Then, I considered the function $y(x)=C(x)e^{2x}$, and $y^{'}(x)=C^{'}(x)e^{2x}+2C(x)e^{2x}$.

By plugging these 2 equations in the initial ODE, I got

$C^{'}(x)=\frac{-x}{e^{2x}}$

Then, I integrated $C'(x)$, and the particular solution , using $C(x)$, is given by

$y_p=\frac{1}{4} (2x+1)$

Then, the general solution is given by

$y(x)=y_h(x)+y_p(x) =\frac{1}{4}(2x+1) +Ce^{2x}$

The question is: why am I allowed to use the method of variation of constants? I understood how to use it, but when I can use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are "allowed" to use a particular method when it works! THAT is how you solve problems.  You TRY something and if it works great.  If it doesn't work, try something else.

Comment: Ok, I tought that the Lagrange method requested that one coefficient should be constant (and in this case should correspond to $2$), and the other a function of $x$